# Programming environment for angular2 without npm

Tags: angular

Due to some restrictions i could not get access to NPM module so is there a alternative way to setup programming environment for angular2 without npm?

I found this stackoverflow question [Development on Angular2 with TS but without NPM 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623270/development-on-angular2-with-ts-but-without-npm) but according to this ts files can be transpiled with in browser. is there any way that i can use to transpile my files in IDE itself?

Answer (score 0):

I know that the **TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin** allows you to build your TypeScript file directly from Sublime. But you need to have a TypeScript compiler globally installed and it seems that the way to install it is from NPM :-(:

```
$ npm install typescript -g
```

Perhaps there are other ways but I don't know them. But then you don't need NPM...

See this link in the section "Build configured project":

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin

An article about Sublime and TypeScript:

- https://cmatskas.com/getting-started-with-typescript-and-sublime-text/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do have typescript installed globally but i don't have angular 2 and its dependencies typed definition files which would be required for transpiling of angular 2 code. According to angular all those files i can get from npm but i don't have access to npm so how can i get access to those files to transpile my ts files locally?

Comment: If its about getting the files, have you checked with NuGet?

Comment: Nuget is also like npm that is not accessible. I'm looking for some reference location or angular 2 typed definition files that i can reference from grunt task to transpile my ts files.