# Typescript Compiler Error TS2307: Cannot find module "angular2/core" when loading from CDN without NPM

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have an example of an angular2 application with typescript, **but without all the node_modules** in my project ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35623270/1107529)). The necessary files are embedded in the `head` of my `index.html` ([as described in example 1 here](https://angular.io/)):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.0/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

Since I want to pre-compile my typescript-files, I installed `node.js` and `tsc`. My editor (PHPStorm 2016.1) automatically compiles the files to `assets/js` as defined in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "declaration": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "outDir": "../assets/js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitBOM": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

The application is loaded with ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35624623/1107529)):

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        'assets/js': {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
System.import( 'assets/js/main' ).then( null, console.error.bind( console ) );
```

On compiling, I always get the (kind of classic) error

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'
```

PHPStorm tells me that it cannot resolve the imports:

[image: curly underline in editor]

even when all the external libraries are loaded:

[image: external libraries in PHPStorm]

But after compiling (even with the above errors) the application is working fine in the browser.

Maybe the Typescript Definition (TSD) is missing ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32581715/1107529)), but tsd is deprecated. I read about `typings install angular --ambient` but I am not sure if this is really necessary (and it throws out a bunch of other errors [like this](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/91)).

**So my question:**

Is this just a side-effect of my setup (without node_modules) which I can ignore, or do I have to install other things?

**My environment:**

- node 5.4.1
- npm 3.3.12
- tsc 1.8.9
- Mac OS X 10.11.4
- PHPStorm 2016.1

I am a little bit lost. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think module needs to be change from `"module": "system",` to `"module": "commonjs",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the problem since the TypeScript compiler can find the Angular2 `.d.ts` files. They are provided when installing Angular2 using NPM (see files `.d.ts` under the folder `node_modules/angular2`).

When setting the `module` property within your `tsconfig.json` file, the compiler will try to find them within the `node_modules` folder.

You can notice that is an issue when compiling the source code but this code will be however compiled and your application able to run...

There are tools like typings and tsd (deprecated) to install manually such typings but Angular2 isn't present in corresponding registries.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. Is it correct then that I have to wait until the typings registries are updated accordingly?