# How to open standalone angular2 and TypeScript project in visual studio

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

How can I open angular2 and TypeScript project in visual studio without npm/nodejs. 
I need to open the project in computer without network.

thank you

Comment: All you need is the Node_modules folder and you can run an angular 2 application

Comment: @Bean0341, How can I compile the typescript to js files?

Comment: aww yes I understand the question now, you have to have something to manage the typescript conversion.... I am of no use here :p However I have also heard of gulp but if you are going to use gulp then you might as well just use npm....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS create new project -> TypeScript -> HTML Application with TypeScript. You will have Typescript transpiler set by default. Now you need angular 2. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623270/development-on-angular2-with-ts-but-without-npm) you need to add these scripts to your page:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.2/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.2/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.2/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.2/http.dev.js">
```

You also have to configure SystemJS as shown in the example i provided earlier.