# How to write angular2 app without node_modules?

Tags: node.js, angular, systemjs

My server-side web project doesn't use npm at all. Now I need to add a new page that needs more SPA feature. I wish to use the newer Angular2, not the old one.

I miss the way that Angular1 can include only a few js files to start working. I know system.js can do this, but all the samples use `npm install` to get node_modules. I also want to avoid this big and fat folder.

Can I write angular2 app without node_modules?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623270/development-on-angular2-with-ts-but-without-npm

Comment: That one was answered at Feb 25 '16, using beta 2, which seems a lot different than current rtm version. I don't think that way is still working now. Or someone can update that answer to rtm version?

Comment: The angular developers have been very vocal about this:  "Node.js and npm are essential to Angular development.".  It is stated in multiple places in the repository and in the documentation.  It definitely may be *possible* to unravel all the dependencies and install them on your own, but it will likely be very **difficult**, and most certainly not ***supported***.

Comment: I'm trying about using an empty angular-cli project's webpack built js as my 'all angular2 bundled js', with app.component.ts/app.module.ts deleted. But facing "Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options." error.